# Azure SQL Server "clr strict security" can this be changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-server

I'm trying to change the 'clr strict security' in Azure SQL Server, but not able, is this no more possible in Azure Managed SQL Server.

I've created a certificate first and then I tried to create a login for the certificate and thats failing as well, is this changed and can this be done in some other way.

`CREATE LOGIN MIRRepoCertLogin FROM CERTIFICATE MIRRepoCert;`
This is also failing with `Keyword or statement option 'CERTIFICATE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server`

My intention was to run the below commands in Azure SQL Server. Any advise.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; 
RECONFIGURE with override;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security', 0; 
RECONFIGURE with override; 
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0; 
RECONFIGURE with override;
```

Comment: When execute the following `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced option', '1';  RECONFIGURE;  EXEC sp_configure;` to list the options, are you seeing the `clr strict security` one?

Comment: I also got the same error message. It seems to be not supported in Azure SQL.

Comment: `Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.` This is what happens when I run sp_confiigure on Azure Managed SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important**
As far as we know, the sp_configure and the SQL Statemenst of Certificate are not supported by Azure SQL Server.

1. When I try to execute the `CREATE LOGIN xxx FROM CERTIFICATE xxx` command. It shows the error is not supported in Azure Managed SQL Server.

[image]

2. When I try to execute the `EXEC sp_configure`  command. It also shows is not supported

[image]

Comment: yes thats what is happening, is there a way to run this in a different manner on Azure SQL Server

Comment: It seems that the current version de Azure SQL does not support this command.

Comment: Got a confirmation that the sp_configure and the SQL Statemenst of Certificate are not supported by Azure SQL Server

Comment: Correctly right, it is not support right now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi@Abhishek. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.